# How do I open the class browser with a specific class?

Tags: smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

Amber Smalltalk version 0.13

In [this project](https://github.com/hhzl/amber-processingJs) I'd like to open the class browser with a specific class.

```
  <button onClick="amber.globals.Browser._openOn_(amber.globals.ProcessingClock)">ProcessingClock class
```

I get the error message `amber not defined`  (see screen shot below).

**Question**
How do I open the browser properly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not defined, `amber` is just a local variable (that is, a parameter) of the loader callback function. Either remember it to some global and reuse in button onclick code (ugly), install onclick handler on the button directly inside loader callback, where you have access to `amber` variable (probably clumsy, but the most clean), or use `require('amber/helpers')` instead of `amber` in direct onclick handlers (in your example you want need to use it twice).

Comment: In case of second soluion, your loading line should look like `require(['app', 'jquery'], function (amber, $) {`, to get jQuery properly via AMD.

Comment: BTW, if you look how sample app generated by `amber init` does this, buttons are not supplied with code in `index.html`, but the task of binding the events is delegated to Smalltalk `#augmentPage`.